# Change resolution in Waking Mars

Tags: resolution, settings

I purchased and installed the humble bundle game "Waking Mars" via the Ubuntu Software Center and it works really well except for some issues with changing settings, namely with the resolution. The in-game settings for changing resolution and entering/exiting fullscreen were easy enough to find and toggle, and when you do it asks to restart the application. When you restart it, all other settings you updated are reflected *except* for the changes to the resolution. (I'm trying to get it to play in windowed mode that fits onto one monitor, but it will only default to windowed mode with the full dual monitor resolution). I noticed that it writes these values to `~/.local/share/WakingMars/UserSettings.ini`. When I change the resolution, it is properly written to in this settings file...but it never is reflected when you restart the application.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was fixed in Waking Mars version 1.0.4 which apparently hasn't been posted in the Software Center just yet.  You can grab it through the Humble Bundle website, however.

Sorry for any inconvenience,

David

Comment: David, I own Waking Mars from the Humble Bundle but still the download link is for version 1.0.3... (as of Dec 22, 2012)

Comment: Nevermind: apparently just the `.deb` file is outdated (but you should look into that!). The `tar.gz` is for version 1.1.